# How to fix an infinite loop when adding a JQuery to my script tags using PHP MVC

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm adding an 'infinite scrolling' image gallery to my PHP MVC using a JQuery file but when I add the .js file into my footer script tags without even adding in the code to access the file my site runs an infinite loop without even scrolling down.

The .js file calls the code on document ready but would need to to grab the first images even before scrolling.

I've added the 'scroll.js' file into my public/js folder and added it into my `footer.php' as standard.

I know that the code works as I have it running in a separate site.

`scroll.js`

```
var start = 0;
var limit = 15;
var reachedMax = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        getData();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
     getData();
});

function getData() {
    if (reachedMax)
        return;

    $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        getData: 1,
        start: start,
        limit: limit
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if (response == 'reachedMax')
            reachedMax = true;
        else {
            start += limit;
            $('.results').append(response);
        }
    }
    });
}
```

This would be caught by the code in my `index.php`;

```
  if (isset($_POST['getData'])) {

    $start = isset($_POST['start']);
    $limit = isset($_POST['limit']);

    $row = $this->imageModel->getPageImages($start, $limit);
    if ($row->num_rows > 0) {
        $response = "";

        while($image = $row->fetch_array()) {
            $response .= '              
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbs/thumb-' . $data['userimage'] . '" alt="">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">'.$data['username'].'</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">'.$data['userimage'].'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';
            }
    }

  }
```

I'm expecting the .js file just to grab the first 15 images but it even seems to loop through loading the page as even the `navbar` is shown repeatedly;

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: Trying Lawrence's suggestion to change to `$start = $_POST['start'] ?? 0;`
I get the following output;
[image: Screenshot 2]

With error `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '15'' at line 18`

Comment: could you add more clear index.php code ..may be problem in $start = isset($_POST['start']); this line of code

Comment: isset returns true/false I think you want `$start = $_POST['start'] ?? 0;` or use a ternary

Comment: @ASHISHSHARMA @Lawrence Cherone. I edited my question to add more of my `index.php` The code works when I am using it in a different website

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I added a screenshot after trying your suggestion and added the code of my `index.php`

Comment: You need to construct an [mcve] - and focus on _minimal_.  In the process, you'll likely find some things that help you troubleshoot this.